# Scala "multilevel" abstract class / abstract objects replacement

Tags: scala, inheritance

I use quite convenient Scala object structure to capture my settings, like below

```
object Settings {
    object ObjectSever {
       val URL = "http://localhost:8081"
       val timeout = 20
    }
    object ConnectionPools {
       object Limits {
          val timeout = 10
          val max = 5
          val prefix = "pref_"
       }
    }
}
```

However, I came to the point where I would need to have multiple instances of following structure, for testing, different config providers etc.
So I tried to build an abstract class out of such structure, however I failed.
I can easily replace `Settings` with just `abstract class`, but how to reproduce such nice, nested structure? 
I would also like to keep a compile-type safety - to get errors when I miss some element in subclasses etc.

Comment: why not read from application.conf of any other resource so you can have diffrent files for tests/prod ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think abstract classes are necessary here since it seems like you just want an immutable data structure without any actual inheritance. Nested case classes should do just fine.

```
case class Settings(server: ObjectServer, connectionPools: ConnectionPools)
case class ObjectServer(URL: String, timeout: Int)
case class ConnectionPools(limits: Limits)
case class Limits(timeout: Int, max: Int, prefix: String)

val settings = Settings(
    ObjectServer(
        URL = "http://localhost:8081",
        timeout = 20
    ),
    ConnectionPools(
        Limits(
            timeout = 10,
            max = 5,
            prefix = "pref_"
        )
    )
)
```

For what it's worth, here's one way to do it with abstract classes and anonymous instantiations of those classes:

```
abstract class Settings {
    val server: ObjectServer
    val connectionPools: ConnectionPools
}

abstract class ObjectServer {
    val URL: String
    val timeout: Int
}

abstract class ConnectionPools {
    val limits: Limits
}

abstract class Limits {
    val timeout: Int
    val max: Int
    val prefix: String
}

object MySettings extends Settings {
    val server = new ObjectServer {
       val URL = "http://localhost:8081"
       val timeout = 20
    }

    val connectionPools = new ConnectionPools {
        val limits = new Limits {
            val timeout = 10
            val max = 5
            val prefix = "pref_"
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I like the second option with abstract classes, its a bit more verbose but I can nest abstract classes to hide the structure, thanks :)

Comment: The disadvantage to the abstract classes is you don't get a nice `copy` method. And the conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use case classes as follows:

```
case class ObjectSever(URL: String = "http://localhost:8081", timeout: Int = 20)
case class Limits(timeout: Int = 10, max: Int = 5, prefix: String = "pref_")
case class ConnectionPools(limits: Limits = Limits())
case class Settings(
    server: ObjectSever = ObjectSever(), 
    pools: ConnectionPools = ConnectionPools())

val setts1 = Settings()
// Settings(
//  ObjectSever(http://localhost:8081,20),
//  ConnectionPools(Limits(10,5,pref_)))

val setts2 = setts1.copy(
  server = setts1.server.copy(URL = "http://stackoverflow.com"),
  pools = setts1.pools.copy(limits = setts1.pools.limits.copy(timeout = 100)))
// Settings(
//  ObjectSever(http://stackoverflow.com,20),
//  ConnectionPools(Limits(100,5,pref_)))

val setts3 = Settings(ObjectSever("http://localhost"))
// Settings(
//  ObjectSever(http://localhost,20),
//  ConnectionPools(Limits(10,5,pref_)))
```